# Equal table size for multiple tables

Tags: tables

I have several tables of each one with 3 columns.
The first and the third columns are the same size for all tables, but the second column is different.

Because the length the line in the second line is different, some tables have small fonts and the second column is wider than other tables.

I would like to have the same with for the second column in all tables and same font size.

This is the way I made all tables:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{tile X}
\resizebox{.8\textwidth}{!}{
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
term ID    & description                & log10 p-value \\ \hline
GO:0000502 & proteasome complex         & -1.5144       \\ \hline
GO:0005575 & cellular\_component        & -0.9977       \\ \hline
GO:0005739 & mitochondrion              & -1.1136       \\ \hline
GO:0034515 & proteasome storage granule & -1.3222       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Should the widths of the first and third columns also match across tables? Are all entries in the first column of the same format as `GO:0000502`, and are all entries in the third column numbers with a minus sign, one digit before the decimal point, and exactly four digits after the decimal point?

Comment: Yes, first and third column hace the same format across all tables and in all cases the length of characters is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all tables to have the same font size while still occupying the same width (of `0.8\textwidth`), don't use the `\resizebox` approach. Instead, load the `tabularx` package, specify the width of each `tabularx` environment to be `0.8\textwidth`, and use `X` (or a suitably modified version of `X`) as the type for the second column. (By "suitably modified", I mean a version of `X` that typesets its material ragged-right while still allowing hyphenation.)

You may also want to consider dropping all vertical lines from the `tabular` (or `tabularx`) environments, dropping most `\hline` directives and replacing the few remaining instances of `\hline` with `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` (three macros provided by the `booktabs` package), respectively. Compare the looks of the two tables below: Which one would you say has a more "open" look and thus invites the reader to linger and actually "read" the table's contents?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{tile X} \label{my-label-X}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{|l|Y|T{-1.4}|}
\hline
term ID    & description         & {log10 p-value} \\ \hline
GO:0000502 & proteasome complex  & -1.5144         \\ \hline
GO:0005575 & cellular\_component & -0.9977         \\ \hline
GO:0005739 & mitochondrion       & -1.1136         \\ \hline
GO:0034515 & proteasome storage granule & -1.3222  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{tile XX} \label{my-label-XX}
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{@{}lYT{-1.4}@{}}
\toprule
term ID    & description         & {log10 p-value} \\ \midrule
GO:0000502 & proteasome complex  & -1.5144       \\ 
GO:0005575 & cellular\_component & -0.9977       \\ 
GO:0005739 & mitochondrion       & -1.1136       \\ 
GO:0034515 & proteasome storage granule & -1.3222 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply loading the `caption` package would make the vertical skip between caption and table more sensible.

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks for this suggestion. I've incorporated it in the example.

Comment: h! is not a float placement one normally should use.

Comment: @MaxNoe - In my view, one shouldn't normally insist on having each and every float appear right where it's encountered in the input file...

Comment: Indeed. So why taking possibilities away from latex by not giving the t, b and p placements?

Comment: So you like to generate warnings? To get clutter in your log?

Comment: @MaxNoe - The `[h!]` is associated only with the second float. It put it there in order to get tight spacing between the two floats, for the sake of generating a compact screen shot. The `[t]`, `[b]`, and `[p]` options would be pointless here, wouldn't they -- except for creating code clutter, which apparently neither you nor I care for :-)

Comment: It seems to be working, but I had to modify two lines: `\newcolumntypince{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumnty`enter code here`pe{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}` to `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}`

Comment: @biorunner88 - Thanks for pointing out the coding issues. I think somebody (well-intentioned, of course) edited my posting and managed to leave behind some code debris. I've fixed the typos now.